# Pass messageID to controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass messageID to my controller, I am not sure how to do this please see my javascript below and controller. Also how would i do somethinglike string message ID do this if its checked etc...

```
$(".markmessage").click(function () {
var messageId=$(this).data("id"); //need to pass this message ID to controller.
//I need to pass the messageID to server which is CRM
$.ajax({
url: "@Url.Action("", "")", //Need to add my URl here
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify({messageID : messageId}), //method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string
dataType: "json",
success: function (response) {
$(this).remove();
}
});
});
```

My controller method for messageID,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult markmessage()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be safe when deploying to production we need to extract the root URL.
In you Layout.cshtml add this ;

```
<script>
        var baseUrl = "@Url.Content("~")";
</script>
```

In your ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + '/Controller/Action', //Need to add my URl here
    type: "POST",
    data: {'messageID' : messageId},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
    });
});
```

In controller
[HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult markmessage(string messageID)
{
    if (messageID == "read do this")
    {
       .. Insert your logic here
    }
}
```

As simple as that, remember URL.Action will not work in javascript because it is for asp only

Comment: `@Url.Action()` will work if the script is in the view (and should **always** be used - and if its an external file, then you pass it to the file via a `data-*` attribute or global variable) - `url: @Url.Action("markmessage")',`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes it will but it's quite messy to mix your javascript in cshtml. By the way i assumed that this is an external js file :D

Comment: Your already doing it - what do you think `var baseUrl = "@Url.Content("~")";` is :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah but at least I can minimize the messy implementation. (y)

Comment: What? as opposed to `var url = '@Url.Action("markmessage")'`? Always generate the url using `@Url.Action()`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes it's feasible but this is for external Js implementation, we practiced to separate our js files for maintainability and easier access

Comment: I give up (at least OP got that part right in the question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay, this just my sentiments and we know we have different POV :) And we are here discussing something but the OP doesn't care for us. In short, no upvote for me :D

Comment: how would i do something like string mesaageID to check if its read do this in a condition

Comment: I want to do a condition on string messageID to check if the ID is read do this.

Comment: @Sam where do you want to put the condition in js or c# side?

Comment: inside c# public action result i.e. if message id is read do this